# Como usar o Enum.Parse()? C#

Tags: c#

Meu código exibe erro ao usar o **Enum.Parse(Console.ReadLine());**

```
namespace Course
{
    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter client data: ");
        Console.Write("Name: ");
        string clientName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string email = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter order data: ");
        Console.Write("Level: (Junior/MidLevel/Senior) ");
        WorkerLevel level = Enum.Parse<WorkerLevel>(Console.ReadLine());

    }



namespace Course.Entities.Enums
{
    enum WorkerLevel : int
    {

        Junior = 0,
        MidLevel = 1,
        Senior = 2
    }
}
}
```

**O GitHub do exercício é este: https://github.com/acenelio/composition1-csharp/tree/master/Course**,

Me aparece o seguinte erro: **Erro CS0308 O método não genérico "Enum.Parse(Type, string)" não pode ser usado como argumentos de tipo Course**

Quem puder me ajudar a sanar esta dúvida agradeço demais, pois é de uma video-aula, e mesmo literalmente copiando o código do professor para mim dá erro e para ele não...

Comment: olá já tentou `(WorkerLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(WorkerLevel), Console.ReadLine())` ? e esse código é em `c#`, remova a tag de `java`

Comment: Opa, amigo. Deu certíssimo. Engraçado que na aula o professor usou "WorkerLevel level = Enum.Parse<WorkerLevel>(Console.ReadLine());"... O que pra mim retornou erro(Embora pra ele não).
Do jeito que você citou acima resolveu o problema perfeitamente...

Comment: o melhor mesmo para evitar a `Exception` é usar o `TryParse`, que caso não seja possível fazer o parse, te retorna `false`, dê uma olhada: [Enum.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-tryparse-1(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-0@)) :)

Comment: @EsdrasLima Provavelmente ele estava usando .NET Core 2+ e você está usando uma versão mais antiga. Na minha resposta tem mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é um erro de compilação, é um tipo de erro que quem está programando vê todo dia e precisa saber interpretá-lo.

Neste caso está a mensagem está clara, mas entendo que possa ser um pouco confuso pra quem está começando.

> O método não genérico "Enum.Parse(Type, string)" não pode ser usado como argumentos de tipo Course

Ou seja, o método `Parse` que está sendo chamado é o [`Enum.Parse(Type, string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netcore-1.1#system-enum-parse(system-type-system-string)), mas você pretende chamar um método `Enum.Parse(string)`.

O erro cita um método com dois parâmetros porque não existe método `Parse` com apenas um parâmetro e um genérico. Ou seja, o compilador está assumindo que você está usando este método com os dois parâmetros
e isso causa o erro.

Dá pra entender a sua confusão porque existe uma assinatura que aceita um genérico e uma string, mas isso [**foi introduzido no .NET Core 2.0**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netcore-2.0) e, aparentemente, você está usando uma versão mais antiga (.NET Core 1.* ou .NET Framework).

Neste caso, o código deveria ser:

```cs
Console.Write("Level: (Junior/MidLevel/Senior) ");
WorkerLevel level = (WorkerLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(WorkerLevel), Console.ReadLine());
```

Note que o ideal é fazer alguma validação dos dados de entrada para garantir que eles estejam no formato esperado ("Junior", "Pleno" ou "Senior") e não acabar quebrando a aplicação no caso de uma digitação errada. Isso pode ser feito usando o método [`Enum.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-1.1). Além de poder fazer a validação dos dados, este método já tem o parâmetro genérico, mesmo nas versões mais antigas do .NET.

O código ficaria assim:

```cs
WorkerLevel level;
Console.Write("Level: (Junior/MidLevel/Senior) ");
if (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out level))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entrada inválida");
    // Fazer algo aqui. Parar a aplicação, solicitar a entrada novamente, etc.
}
```

Comment: Sim, amigo... De fato. Minhas dúvidas foram esclarecidas. Obrigado.
Eu realmente estava(E estou) usando o .NET Framework.
Muito esclarecedor. Tudo de bom!

Comment: @EsdrasLima Se a resposta serviu você pode marcá-la como correta usando o ✔ abaixo da quantidade de votos no lado esquerdo.

Comment: Tudo bem amigo, Irei fazer. Sou usuário novo... Obrigado novamente.
Detalhe: Atualizei a versão e agora está tudo funcionando perfeitamente, assim como na video-aula. Tmj!!

Comment: @EsdrasLima Ótimo. Pra aprender tem que ser .NET 6 mesmo.